# Fabric: rsync between two remote hosts

Tags: rsync, fabric

I want rsync files from remote Production server to remote Backup server using Fabric.

Server credentials stored in my local `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host backup
     HostName 1.1.1.1
     Port 33333
     User swasher

Host production
    HostName 2.2.2.2
    Port 44444
    User swasher
```

Now I want run rsync on Production machine, and I need insert host/user/name of Backup server in this command, something like this

```
@hosts('production')
def backup():
    run("rsync -avz  -e 'ssh -p {PORT}' /from/ {USER}@{HOST}:/to/'.format(backup.PORT, backup.USER, backup.HOST))
```

How I can get credential of Backup server to run rsync?

Answer (score 0):

Not w fabric but it does the job

try this to copy dirs and nested subdirs from local to remote:

```
cmd = "sshpass -p {} scp -r {}/* root@{}://{}".format(
    remote_root_pass, 
    local_path, 
    remote_ip, 
    remote_path)
os.system(cmd)
```

don't forget to import os, You may check the exitcode returned (0 for success)

Also you might need to "yum install sshpass"

And change /etc/ssh/ssh_config StrictHostKeyChecking ask to: StrictHostKeyChecking no